# Link two websites with the onclick property?

Tags: javascript

I have a login page and a content page. Pressing the login button will open the content page in a new tab but I want it to open in the same tab. Tried `window.location.href` but it doesn't work for some reason.

```js
function validate() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (username == "marin" && password == "12345678") {
    window.open("file:///C:/Users/lukam/OneDrive/Radna%20povr%C5%A1ina/stranica/stranica1_1.html")
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("login je pogresan")
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="Username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="Username" id="username">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn-submit" onclick="validate()">Login</button>
```

Comment: "i tried window.location.href" — You haven't shown us that. You haven't even shown us a complete [mcve] for your attempt to do something different.

Comment: Some browsers disable to set `loaction.href` to `file://` urls.

Comment: is this a better minimal reproducible example example ? im new to coding in general and here so i didnt know

Comment: what do you mean by 'in the same tab'?

Comment: when i say in the same tab i mean that when you input the username and password and click the button it opens the new page in the same site where you put in the info but for me it opens a whole new chrome tab